# How can I use lottiefiles in loading page in nextjs Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, lottie

How can I use `lottie` in nextjs project `(App Structure)` for loading project to load an animated logo
-- I tried to add `"use client"`; but no thing happens and tried import Lottie from `react-lottie` as a dynamic import but the same problem happens no animation on screen but if I change any value of the component after it's mounted it shows the animation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got it working with the following code and npm package:

```js
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
import animationData from "@/public/lotties/dog1.json";

export default function loading() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-full justify-center items-center">
      <Lottie
        animationData={animationData}
        className="flex justify-center items-center"
        loop={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).